# ODBC Driver for Progess on Debian

Tags: php, odbc, openedge, progress-db

All,

I am trying to install and get working the progress ODBC driver for Debian.
I have installed the progress driver no problem, however, when I try to connect in PHP using ODBC_Connect I get an error:

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1022.so' : file not found, SQL state 01000 in SQLConnect
```

Next step was for me to see if the file existed and if that file had all of its dependencies. 
So I issued the following command:

```
ldd /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1022.so
```

And got the following:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb773e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7505000)
libpgicu22.so => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7500000)
libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb74da000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7375000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb773f000)
```

Now I am stumped! I cannot get hold of the missing files.

Anyone able to assist at all please?

Regards
Col

Comment: Related issue in the Knowledgebase? http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P148633

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always helpful to mention the versions of Progress, Linux, PHP and so forth that you are using.

Setting that aside for now.  You say that you installed the ODBC driver "no problem".  To confirm that you have done so and that the problem is external to the ODBC drivers you should first try a test connection with the supplied sqlexp utility.

From a Linux command shell start "proenv".  This will properly set all the needed environment.  Then run "sqlexp -u username -p password -db dbname -S port#"

That should get you a prompt where you can enter SQL queries etc.

If that works then you have all of the files needed from Progress' POV and the issue would be in your ODBC setup (odbc.ini).  If it does not work then you likely have a Progress/OS release mismatch.

Comment: Tom, I was able to connect via sqlexp as you explained, thank you. I assume that this means the problem is with my ODBC file so I will now look down that road.

Comment: OK.
I am still stumped!
The command line is working perfectly using sqlexp.
Running an 'ldd /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1022.so',these 2 missing libraries seem to not exist on the Internet!

libpgicu22.so => not found
libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 => not found

I am still trying to connect using PHP using:
$connstr = "Driver=FreeTDS;Server=192.168.169.100;Port=2603;Database=progress;";

I now am at a stand still, any help or some direction would be very much appreciated.

Cheers 
Col